# How to test for non existing html tag in rspec/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails

For a controller delivering some html snippet (used as ajax call), I have a view spec looking like that:

```
it "should not contain html element" do
    render
    rendered.should have_selector('div')
    rendered.should_not have_selector('html')
end
```

Since our ajax content loader doesn't allow a full html page to be rendered, I want to check that the result does not contain an html tag.

For now the result in `rendered` is a simple div tag:

```
puts rendered
```

leads to

```
"<div>Some text</div>"
```

However, the test fails:

```
Failure/Error: rendered.should_not have_selector('html')
  Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
  expected not to find css "html", found 1 match: "Some text"
```

I also tried it with

```
rendered.should_not have_xpath('//html')
rendered.should_not have_css('html')
rendered.should have_no_xpath('//html')
rendered.should have_no_css('html')
```

but the result stays the same.

Why is a check for `html` matching the text **inside** the `div`? Even a test for `body` leads to the same result.

Comment: Try to `puts rendered` to see actual value while test runs

Comment: Already did that and I mentioned it in my text (maybe not clear enough): "<div>Some text</div>"
Most interesting - as I see it - is the fact, that it found the html inside the text.

Comment: I know that Nokogiri before doing any parsing, fixes the html you pass to it in order to make it valid which includes wrapping it into an html tag. I _think_ that capybara at some level does the same thing. In other words, `should_not have_selector('html')` will never pass, even if the initial html you provide is only a partial.

Comment: Thanks!
At least, inside capybara, I found that `Capybara::Node::Simple` calls `Nokogiri::HTML` which might do exactly what you describe.
Now it would be interesting to know if there's a way to avoid that by using a different selector, a different approach at all or just by or specifying some parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be possible using the capybara matchers, because capybara is using Nokogiri::HTML to generate the internal DOM structure, and this always tries to create a valid HTML representation, which also includes an html and body tag, if there is none. See [here in their source](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/simple.rb#L21).

If you want to do that, you could fork capybara and change that line into something like

```
native = Nokogiri::HTML::Fragment(native) if native.is_a?(String)
```

`Nokogiri::HTML::Fragment` will not try to enhance the code to have an completed html structure.

Another solution would simply be doing a string match:

```
rendered.match('<html').should be nil
```

Comment: I like the string matching idea and you could probably load up the rendered string into a Nokogiri fragment to use fancy css selectors.

Comment: Yep – I found it in the code and mentioned it my comment above as well. Currently I'm matching something like you mentioned, but it's not 100%… just for completeness and understanding I'll try the Fragment. Thanks for your help and sharing insight.

Answer (score 0):

What about this way of checking? (and throwing in a wait_until to make sure the page loads properly before you assert)

```
assert_false wait_until { page.has_selector?('html')} , "Found some stuff when it shouldn't have.."
```

I'm using this btw...

> gem 'capybara', '1.1.4'

Comment: I can test your suggestion tomorrow, but I don't see why this would help. I will check docu for wait_until. However, my problem is that the page does not and will never contain a <html> tag, but testing for exactly this behaviour fails.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. No matter if I put or don't put an html tag into my template, your test always passes.